# require some sort of loop or jumping statement for my code

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, csv

well i am new to C#, and implementing a code, in which i have two buttons, with one acting as starting of data acquisition and storing it in a csv file and other button to stop it.

well codes for all these are as follows:

//button for start DAQ

```
    private void stdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stopped = false;

       process();


    }
```

//button for stoping DAQ

```
    private void spdaq_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        stopped = true;
    }
```

// process function

```
private process()
    {
            int iAvail = 0;
            int iRead = 0;

            string filename = @textBox3.Text;// taking csv file name from user
       // jit:

            //a function calculating the total number of values and storing it in iAvail



            int[] iRawData = new Int32[iAvail];
            double[] dScaledData = new Double[iAvail];


            //a function transferring the data from buffer and storing it in dscaledData array

            List<double> data = new List<double>();
            for (int i = 0; i < iAvail; i++)
            {
                data.Add(dScaledData[i]);
            }

            Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()
                                     => 
                                     {
                                         while (stopped == false)
                                         {
                                             Write(data.ToArray(), filename);
                                            // goto jit;
                                         }
                                     });


    }
```

// csv creater and data writer

```
public static void Write(double[] data, string outputPath)
    {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < data.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            if (stopped) break;
            sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", data[i]));
        }

        if (File.Exists(outputPath))
        {
            File.AppendAllText(outputPath, sb.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            File.WriteAllText(outputPath, sb.ToString());
        }
    }
```

this is what i am implementing, and the problem with this code is that when the data is first transferred and written to the file, then again the same data is written again and again irrespective of new data and i tried implementing that Goto statement(can be seen in comments) but it is giving error - " Control cannot leave the body of an anonymous method or lambda expression ", and if i don't use the While loop the data is not written at all.

**So i want to call my process function and to transfer data to csv starting on press of a start button, take fresh data everytime and write it to csv or can say call the process method again from it's start point and to stop it on click of the stop button, but i am unable to do it irrespective of various tries with different loops and some threading functions also.**

please help with this.

Comment: It's maybe because `a function transferring the data from buffer and storing it in dscaledData array` is not in the loop.

Comment: @Dzienny, please give me some code for the same

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you only need to `Write` once, you should remove this or change it from `while` to `if`:

```
while (stopped == false)
```

The loop will cause `Write` to be called infinitely until `stopped` becomes `true`.

Also, you might want to change `Write` to `return` rather than `break` if `stopped` is `true`, so that you don't write anything if you are supposed to be stopping:

```
        if (stopped) break;
```

to

```
        if (stopped) return;
```

---

If you want to generate `data` again and really do want to loop forever, just move that code into the loop:

```
Task myFirstTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(()
     => 
     {
         while (stopped == false)
         {
             List<double> data = new List<double>();
             // TODO: Generate data here - move all relevant code here

             Write(data.ToArray(), filename);
         }
     });
```

Comment: while it's like i want to check the buffer again and again but if the data is redundant then just leave that data and stop there

Comment: You're only assigning to `data` once, so you'll just write the same piece of data over and over if you retain the loop...

Comment: please give some code for the same, i had triad various hits and trials with which some times it's giving output sometimes it's just idle and gives output only on a start click, so totally confused

Comment: If you want to keep on looping but with new data each time, move the code which creates the data into the loop. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a job for the ***BackgroundWorker***.

This code will start you up:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    int loopCounter = 0;        // variable just used for illustration      
    private static BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();        // The worker object

    // This function does your task
    public void doSomeStuff(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            loopCounter = i;    // Pass the loop count to this variable just to report later how far the loop was when the worker got cancelled.
            Thread.Sleep(100);  // Slow down the loop

            // During your loop check if the user wants to cancel
            if (bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                return; // quit loop
            }
        }
    }

    // This button starts your task when pressed
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;   // Set the worker to support cancellation
        bw.DoWork += doSomeStuff;               // initialize the event
        if (!bw.IsBusy)                         // Only proceed to start the worker if it is not already running.
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();                // Start the worker
        }
    }

    // This button stops your task when pressed
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Request cancellation
        bw.CancelAsync();

        textBox1.Text = "The bw was cancelled when 'loopCounter' was at: " + loopCounter.ToString();

    }

}
```